# How does p really works as related to content put in registers?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, visual-block

I've read [this question and answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9656/how-does-p-command-work-in-vim) already, however it could not solve my doubts.

As far as my understanding is correct, `p` always has the same effect (`p`utting the content of a register, by default the `"` register).

Different effects of the `p` command are actually a consequence of different contents of the register(s) that we put. In this respect, given the sample text

```
-----------
---moree---
---lines---
---oftxt---
-----------
moree---
---l
```

I notice the following:

1. `y`anking/`d`eleting character-wise `more` into a register fills the register with `more`;
2. `y`anking/`d`eleting line-wise `---moree---` into a register fills the register with `---more---^J`, where `^J` is a single caracter representing the linefeed `<NL>`;
3. `y`anking/`d`eleting block-wise the alphabetic rectangle fills the register with `moree^Jlines^Joftxt`, where `^J` has the same meaning as above.

However:

- Concerning 2 as compared to 1 and 3, how can something (`^J`) **later** in the register affect where the `p`utting action **starts**?
- Concerning 1 and 2 as compared to 3,

  - `y`anking a `v`isual selection going from the first `m` to the first `l` will fill the register with `moree---^J---l`,
  - `y`anking a block `CTRL-V`isual selection of the last two lines (obtained by <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>) fills the register exactly with the same content `moree---^J---l`,
  - however putting the two registers will have a different effect.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Besides, is it possible to get `^J` in text just as can get `^M` in text by <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, `^[` by <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> and so on?

Comment: RE the last question: `Ctrl-V` + `Ctrl-M` then `:set fileformat=mac`  ;)

Comment: Just to clarify: p pastes from registers (you use the term in most of your Q, but you say buffer at the top, and that has a very different meaning in vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as my understanding is correct, p always has the same effect (pasting the content of a buffer, by default the " buffer).

In Vim they say "putting", not "pasting". And what is more important, that particular "thing" is called "a register", so to find a relevant help topic you should type: `:h registers`, not `:h buffers` (which will lead you to a totally different place).

Another (more subtle) point is that although the documentation says "unnamed register", but, in fact, `"` is *a pointer to the last register used*. So, for example, after the `yank` command (without explicit register override) `"` points to a register named `0`, and after `delete` it points to the register `1`, etc.

> however pasting the two registers will have a different effect.

That's easy. Besides "contents" all registers also have "type" which is normally deduced automatically. In your case `:echo getregtype('"')` will print different values, and so `p` will behave differently too.

Comment: +1 and accepted (even though the idea that the textual content of the register was enough to determine the effect of `p` with no need to have such a thing as the type of the register was cooler). The comment about the `"` being a pointer to the last register used is illuminating.